# Are identically distributed variables sufficient for stationarity? if so of what kind?

Tags: statistics, time-series, stationary-processes

If I have variables $Y_t, t = 1, 2, ..$ which are identically distributed, is the time series $(Y_t)$ stationary? If so is it weakly stationary or strictly stationary?

Bonus question what are sufficient conditions for weak and strict stationarity? What are necessary conditions?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are these variables independent in some way, or correlated?

Comment: No assumptions about the dependency structure